# nginx add_headers on location blocks are dropped

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I've googled but not found solution to my issue:

```
add_header X-debug-message "debug-msg 1" always;
location ^~ /backend {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /back.php?$args;
   add_header X-debug-message "debug-msg 2" always;
}
add_header X-debug-message "debug-msg 3" always;
```

So, for the `/backend` location, I can see only `"debug-msg 1"` and `"debug-msg 3"` headers. Why I don't see `"debug-msg 2"`? I am sure the `/backend` location block is entered.

Answer (score 0):

Yep. It's behaviour as [documented](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header):

*There could be several add_header directives. These directives are inherited from the previous level if and only if there are no add_header directives defined on the current level*

You shall take a look at more_set_headers as a replacement

Comment: The meaning of that sentence is that "debug-msg 2" will override "debug-msg 1" header. But the truth is that "debug-msg 2" never is grabbed. It's more... removing "debug-msg 1" and "debug-msg 3" lines stay only with "debug-msg 2", this one is not grabbed either.